# Generating a JSON file with nested arrays for loading a game level

Tags: arrays, json, libgdx

I want to load levels from a json file for my tower defence game.I tried many json generator websites but I couldn't get the exact thing that I want.

I want something like ;

-- Level

----Wave

------Enemy (enemyType,spawnTime)

For example:  level[2].wave[3].enemy[1].enemyType  should return the enemyType.

Levels are composed of waves and waves are composed of enemies. All enemies has a 2 variable which are enemyType and spawnTime.

Comment: And what's your question now? Why don't you write the JSON yourself?

Comment: Use libgdx's `Json` class. Create the structure in code and then just do Json.toJson(level, Level.class, file);

Comment: Thank you noone it really make sense for complex hierarchies, it would be the better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a hard task. However, JSON won't handle implementation of abstract classes/interfaces. That means,

```
Enemy e = new Skeleton();
```

can't be serialized with JSON and then read. You will have to make a workaround like saving String of the class name and then load it through something like

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.my.cool.package.enemy." + "Skeleton");
Enemy e = (Enemy) clazz
.getConstructor(Vector2.class, int.class)
.newInstance(new Vector2(0, 10), 5);
```

Okay, back to the main question, do it like this:

```
class Enemy {
    String className;
    int spawnTime;
}

class Wave {
    Enemy[] enemies;
}

class Level {
    Wave[] waves;
}
```

then create your level:

```
Level l = new Level();
l.waves = new Wave[1];
l.waves[0].enemies = new Enemies[1];

l.waves[0].enemies[0] = new Enemy();
l.waves[0].enemies[0].className = "Skeleton";
l.waves[0].enemies[0].spawnTime = 5;
```

don't forget to import libgdx JSON (more info on [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-%26-writing-JSON)).

```
Json json = new Json();
System.out.println(json.prettyPrint(l));
```

this should print out your level, just use json.toJson(l) for smaller output. (But not that pretty.) To load it, use:

```
Json json = new Json();
String text = json.prettyPrint(l);
Level level = json.fromJson(Level.class, text);
```